# How to handle java imports from two diffrent jar in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have maven project which contain two jars `jersey-core-1.18.1` and `jaxrs-api-3.0.1.Final`  and both jar have Response.java class with inside same package  `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`

Some places i want to use `jersey-core-1.18.1`  and some places i will want to use `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`.

But eclipse showing only one `import javax.ws.rs.core.Response` and this is referring to `jersey-core-1.18.1`.

What changes i have to make so both jar file import will available?

Comment: Related: [Import conflict - because of same package structure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34609090)

Comment: I would not call that a good idea. You'll have to *start* by writing a class loader (and unloader).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing With Duplicate Fully Qualified Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823048/dealing-with-duplicate-fully-qualified-names)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Actually I have to test Retry Mechanism   which is not available with Jercey then only i will totally delete Jercey jars and refer Resteasy jar .But for testing purpose with my project i have to use it like this.

Answer (score 2):

The first jar on the build path at execution time which has the class needed "wins".  What you are doing is very dangerous because any reordering of jars on the classpath after you built it will change the behaviour of your program.

Therefore you should only have a single version of the classes in question on your build path (even though they may exist in several copies).   Upgrade or downgrade your current artifacts or find others which allow this.